# What is the & mark meaning ahead a variable in vim?

Tags: help-system

I read echo help file and find a command:
`:echo "the value of 'shell' is" &shell`

I wonder what is '&shell' here.

I check the help file for "&", "variables", "shell" and havent find any useful information. So what is the "&" meaning here. And what should I do to figure it out by myself?

Comment: Try this: `:h :let-&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And what should I do to figure it out by myself?

Do `:help &<C-d>` and "figure out" which tag is more likely to help you (list is approximative, YMMV):

```
&            't_&8'       /\&      :&         :&&    :let-&    :set-&
:set-&vi     :set-&vim    cpo-&    expr-&&    g&     s/\&      t_&8
```

- `&` is normal mode `&`, irrelevant,
- `'t_&8'` has a `t_` but `&shell` has not, irrelevant,
- `/\&` looks like it is related to search, irrelevant,
- `:&` and `:&&` look like they are Ex commands, irrelevant,
- `:let-&` looks like it has something to do with variables, relevant,
- all the `:set-` seem related, relevant,
- `cpo-&` is related to `:help 'cpoptions'`, irrelevant,
- `expr-&&` has two `&`s, irrelevant,
- `g&` appears to be normal-mode-something, irrelevant,
- `s/\&` looks like it is related to substitutions, irrelevant,
- `t_&8` is the same as the other but without quotes, weird and irrelevant.

So that leaves you with `:help :let-&` and a couple of others:

```
:help :let-&
:let &{option-name} = {expr1}           *:let-option* *:let-&*
        Set option {option-name} to the result of the
        expression {expr1}.
```

Hooo…

But you are not supposed to open random help sections and "figure it out by yourself". What you are supposed to do is follow the user manual (`:help user-manual`), which teaches you things in the proper order. `&optionname` is explained in the chapter about scripting Vim: `:help 41.3`.

Comment: https://vimhelp.org/ you mean this is the user manual?

Comment: Yes and no. The user manual is a part of that. I edited the answer with the command that leads you to the user manual in Vim.

Comment: Lol, i did read the user manual early on… and now I open random help when I need it :)